# Commas causing issue in $ value String to Float conversion

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert dollar amounts from a text file to a stored numeric type (therefore 'String' to float,BigDecimal,etc)

Problem is that some of the strings include commas: 1,270.00, 22,835.22, etc and return a "*java.lang.NumberFormatException*:" when trying to be converted.

```
String GrossEarnings = null;

GrossEarnings = br.readLine();

float GE = Float.parseFloat(GrossEarnings);



String GrossEarnings = null;

GrossEarnings = br.readLine();

BigDecimal GE = new BigDecimal(GrossEarnings);
```

Is there a way to convert a String of numbers with commas to a numeric type?  Or do the commas have to be removed?

Comment: Show how you do the conversion

Comment: Yes there are ways to do that. Quite possibly it's a minor modification from how you're currently doing it. Since you complain about an exception you get with your current code, you should post your current code as an [mcve].

Comment: @Jim Garrison Attached 2 examples: with float and with BigDecimal

Comment: Is the "dot" always the the decimals separator? Just replace the commas for nothing and you are good to go

Comment: Also read about the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, but there are thousands of them and I would like to avoid doing that

Comment: Since you are reading one by one it will not be costly.

Comment: Trying to use a NumberFormat for each different format to convert it will be even costlier.

Comment: @JorgeCampos that's premature optimization. NumberFormats are there for this purpose.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt well I agree, although depending on how often this will occur I would go for the KISS principle. And for the OP's problem it seems a one time solution, so why bother?

Comment: I should think something like this may work: `float GE = Float.parseFloat(GrossEarnings.replace(",", ""));`.